# Loading only the middle section when a tag is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web

How do most websites load only the middle section of the page when you click on a link (a-tag)? If this is done through AJAX then how does that change the URL to the given href in the a tag? I know I can use the .load function, but this doesn't change the URL to the one given in the href of the link.

Answer (score 0):

If on a link click content is loaded into some interior section of a website, it's usually fetched asynchronously by means of AJAX and injected into the DOM structure. The URL of the site does not change during this process.

Consider the following example with three different links. Using jQuery, for each of the links the default navigation is disabled and instead content is injected into the main content `div`.

#### HTML

```
<nav>
    <a href="some href 1">Link 1</a> |
    <a href="some href 2">Link 2</a> |
    <a href="some href 3">Link 3</a>
</nav>
<div id="main"></div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('nav a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link navigation

        // This is the point where you could fetch content (for instance
        // from the href of the clicked link). For this example we just
        // generate a string containing the href.
        var content = 'Content for ' + $(this).html();

        $('#main').html(content); // Inject the content
    });
});
```

Check out the live demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uopzavqf/).

Comment: Thanks!! But, I wanted to know how I could change the URL while doing what you have just mentioned.

Comment: @user3648939 That's not possible because changing the URL will always load the new site. The only way would be if the new site would look exactly like the current one with just the content section replaced. But still you'd notice the loading process as a user.

Comment: I have seen such behavior in facebook and other sites, where the left section and the topbar is always loaded and only the active section changes. The URLs change there.